# ionic 4 how to change slide by click on button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, slider, ionic4

I am using slides but I need to change the slide on button click.

Example Code

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
   Slide one 
  <ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
   Slide Two
  <ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<button (click)="next()" >Next</button>
```

I need to change the slide when i click on next button thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to use it :

```
<ion-slides #slides>
  <ion-slide>
   Slide one 
  <ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
   Slide Two
  <ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<button (click)="next(slides)" >Next</button>
```

in your ts file, add the method for next:

```
next(slides){
    slides.slideNext(); // slide to next
}
```

If you want to slide to previous use `slidePrev()`.
Here's [the documentation about slides.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#methods)